# Pinch to Zoom misbehaving in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

Everything was working fine (I had pinch to zoom and pan working), I was adding in a few stack views to display data and control a few things, and now my pinch to zoom is all funky.  It zooms upwards, and no matter how hard I try I can't zoom straight or downwards. Hopefully this quick [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm0lj.jpg) shows it. I also threw in some photos of the scroll and image view attributes and size inspectors if that is where I screwed up.

I tried deleting and re adding the image and scroll view in case I screwed something up to get it back to default but it's still happening.  I've seen others use this code a few times and it works just fine, but just in case I've got something wrong I'll add in the code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 8.0
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: can i see your constraints of scrollview and imageView ?

Comment: @RadheYadav no problem. I added those to the imgur link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: see]

see in my picture i have set constraint of canvas with respect to scrollview so i think u have to change your all  imageview constraints (top bottom leading and trailing) with scrollview to make it work for pinch to zoom